# base class pointer, invoke method based on derived type

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I understand that the following code doesn't work -- can't convert base to foo.

Is there something I can do, or some pattern to employ which would get me close the behavior I'm trying to achieve in the code below? IOW, if I have a base class pointer to a derived type, how can I invoke a specific method that matches the derived type (not the base type)?

What patterns might I use? I looked into Curiously Recursive (or recurring) Template Pattern, however this imposed other limitations itself.

```
class base {};
class foo : public base {};
void method(const foo& f){}
int main(){
  base* b = new foo();
  method(*b);
}
```

Comment: This is the whole point of type safety.  The compiler doesn't *know* the dynamic type (in general), so it refuses to compile.

Comment: You're probably interested in the Visitor pattern.

Comment: read up on virtual methods (virtual member functions) in your C++ textbook.

Comment: @Quentin the visitor pattern fits my needs perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to just make `method()` a `virtual` member function on `foo`:

```
class base { 
 public:
  virtual void method() const = 0;
};
class foo : public base {
 public:
  void method() const override { }
};

int main(){
  foo f;
  base* b = &f;
  b->method();
}
```

But if for some reason that is not possible (perhaps you don't have access to `method()` or perhaps you want to keep the logic in `method()` separate from `foo`) you could use a simplified version of the [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

The visitor pattern relies on all the classes in your hierarchy having a virtual function to dispatch based on class type.

In your case you don't need double-dispatch so you don't actually need the visitor object and can just call your `method` function directly from a virtual `dispatch` function:

```
class base { 
 public:
  virtual void dispatch() const = 0;
};
class foo : public base {
 public:
  void dispatch() const override;
};

void method(const foo& f){}

void foo::dispatch() const {
  method(*this);
}

int main(){
  foo f;
  base* b = &f;
  b->dispatch();
}
```

You have to remember that in most contexts the compiler doesn't know that your `base` pointer is actually of type `foo`.

Comment: Awesome! Visitor pattern is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you sir!

Answer (score 1):

Use `virtual` functions to solve these kinds of problems:

```
class base {
  public:
    virtual void func() const { /* A */ }
};
class foo : public base {
  public:
    void func() const override { /* B */ }
};
void method(const base& f) {
    f.func();
}
int main(){
  base* b = new foo();
  method(*b);
}
```

Now, depending on the actual type of `f`, either `A` or `B` code will be executed in `method`.